# Updated Android Studio Applcation design got really small

Tags: android, android-studio, screen-density

Hi I have a application puzzle game for android I am using android studio to develop it, I have recently update android studio and my design of the map is very small I have not change any of the code.

What it was:

[image: image 1]

What it looks like now:

[image: image 2]

Can anyone help me please.

Comment: Are you running the app on a higher density display in the second image? Do you have a different png for each density?

Comment: It is the same display as the first picture I am running the same verions of my code with the same display on a earlier version of android studio and its working ;/

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 image with 2 different pixels . you should check the screen size of virtual device or mobile phone used for run app . 
note you may have used small image in the drawable or mipmap dir

i hope useful for u

Comment: its the same screen display for both of the images

Comment: check your size of image's too

Comment: they are the same images

Comment: No . Check your image in drawable or mipmap . You should use this image of puzzle game in mipmap-hdpi and mipmap-mhdpi and .. by diferent size . Larger image's and diferent in this directories . Good luck

Comment: ale the design of the main menu has changed not just the map design it seems like the buttons are further away